# Can the word "exposure" be used to mean something positive?

Tags: connotations

I want to say something along the lines of: "I believe that the exposure I would gain through being involved in such a wide range of tasks would enable me to..." (that's not the exact sentence, so ignore any potential grammatical issues with the rest of this sentence)

To me this seems fine but doing some searching, it seems "exposure" normally has a negative connotation whereas here I am using it in such a way that it would be positive - i.e. I would gain experience through (being exposed to) a variety of things etc.

Is this acceptable?

Comment: No, your first idea is right: to get or gain exposure to [A] by doing [B]. That is not negative at all. Exposure to harmful chemicals is negative.

Comment: The first two definitions don't look negative: ***exposure***: a) An act of subjecting or an instance of being subjected to an action or an influence: *their first exposure to big city life.*
b) Appearance in public or in the mass media: *an actor with much recent exposure in television.* http://www.thefreedictionary.com/exposure

Comment: Their exposure to harmful chemicals is A). that's why dictionaries don't always provide good explanations for words in context.

Comment: Why don't you just use 'experience' instead of 'exposure'? The latter word, exposure, can sound "funny" because it goes have negative connotations in some contexts.

Answer (score 1):

An "exposure" is something that is likely to lead to a (non-trivial) result. That result could be either positive or negative, and therefore an "exposure" could be either positive or negative.